# Provide some extra space at the end of ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
Below is my code, I want to add some extra space of height 50, which comes at the end of list item. because when my second child of stack appears it nearly overlaps the last item of list view. I've tried wrapping ListView.builder with column and added a container at last but destroyed my whole structure. for this scenario I've to wrap the column into Single scrollable which pushed stack 2nd widget to be at the end of ListItem.(But I don't want Stack 2nd object to be scrollable).
As you can see I'm not able to click on HotDog.

```
 body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: itemData.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){ 
                   return Text(data[index].name);
 }

                     ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                color: Colors.cyan
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 60,

            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be easily done by adding bottom padding in listview.builder

```
Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100), //Increase this as per your requirment
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (cxt , idx) {
           return YourWidget();
          }
```

Answer (score 9):

How about you add empty last item like below code?

```
          ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: itemData.length + 1,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                   if (index == item.Data.length) {
                       return SizedBox(height: 50);
                   } else {
                       return Text(data[index].name);
                   }
                 }
            ),
```

Comment: That's a good way but what if the items he have exceeds the phone's height. Ex: having 10 of those items. Adding an extra SizedBox at the bottom of the items won't be enough.

Comment: @uni Hm... I added a item of list. so I think that whatever phone's height the list cannot exceeds height.

Comment: What do you mean @Kuku? Sorry I didn't get what you meant with your second sentence. This solution that you provided would work but only when the height of all items in the listview combined are the same as the phone's height. You are only adding a SizedBox at the end of the list right? So when there are too many items on the list, the SizedBox doesn't get shown. It only gets shown on the end of the list. Hope this clarifies what I'm trying to say. You still have a good answer but it doesn't apply to listviews with many items.

Comment: Good Luck with your projects :)

Answer (score 4):

`ListViewBuilder` should be wrap inside Expanded widget which will take fullscreen 
and give container bottom width as per need.

**Example:**

```
var itemData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
     Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: itemData.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Container(
                                height: 80,
                                child: Text("Text :" + index.toString()));
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            color: Colors.cyan),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        height: 60,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],


 ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This also works. It is an alternative from using the Positioned widget :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're listview.builder is inside a stack, you simply use the Positioned widget for this. Simply wrap your listview with Positioned like below:

```
Positioned(
 bottom:50, //adjust this since this is the padding inside the stack
  child:Container(
width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width //width of the whole phone
child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemData.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){ 
           return Text(data[index].name);
    }
  ),
 ),
),
```

To ensure your Container stays at the bottom wrap it with a positioned widget and set the bottom property to 0:

```
Positioned(
 bottom:0, //adjust this since this is the padding inside the stack
  child:Container(),
),
```

Here is a one minute clip showing how to use the Positioned widget: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ

Comment: Hey @Uni, I have tried your approach but getting this error. "Failed assertion: line 1648 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true."

Comment: @PraveenGupta you have to wrap it with a container. I updated the answer

Comment: Whenever I'm providing Bottom value in positioned wigdet,it takes me to the bottom of the screen and I'm not able to scroll anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to do it by default you have to do it manually with own logic

```
          ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: itemData.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){ 
                   if(index == itemData.length - 1 )
                     return Padding(

                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom : 50),
                      child : Text(data[index].name)
                   );
                   return Text(data[index].name);
                 }),
```